# Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to PHP, so this is confusing me a little. I'm using the Woocommerce plugin for Wordpress and I'm trying to add a custom field to display rental prices for certain products. However, not all products have a rental option, so I want this to only display on products that I give a rental price.

Here's the code I'm using, which works fine. The only problem is that it displays a rental price of $0 on products I haven't specified a rental price. Instead of display $0, I just want it to not display at all.

```
//add rental field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_rent_product_field' );
function wc_rent_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => 'rent_price', 'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 'label' => __( 'rent', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')' ) );
}

//save rental field
add_action( 'save_post', 'wc_rent_save_product' );
function wc_rent_save_product( $product_id ) {
    // If this is a auto save do nothing, we only save when update button is clicked
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['rent_price'] ) ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $_POST['rent_price'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'rent_price', $_POST['rent_price'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'rent_price' );
}

//display rental field
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_rent_show', 5 );
function wc_rent_show() {
    global $product;
    // Do not show this on variable products
    if ( $product->product_type <> 'variable' ) {
        $rent = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rent_price', true );
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">';
        _e( 'Rent: ', 'woocommerce' );
        echo '<span class="woocommerce-rent-price">' . woocommerce_price( $rent ) . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this? I've searched around the internet looking for an answer, but it seems to be going over my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ( $product->product_type <> 'variable' ) {
    $rent = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rent_price', true );
    if($rent)>0
    {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">';
    _e( 'Rent: ', 'woocommerce' );
    echo '<span class="woocommerce-rent-price">' . woocommerce_price( $rent ) . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I was looking for and after a little tweaking to the above answer the following code displays an annual rental price only for products with a rental price. It also orders the rental price to display after the RRP and discount prices on both the single product and archive pages.

```
//add rental field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_rent_product_field' );
function wc_rent_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => 'rent_price', 'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 'label' => __( 'Annual Rental', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')' ) );
}

//save rental field
add_action( 'save_post', 'wc_rent_save_product' );
function wc_rent_save_product( $product_id ) {
    // If this is a auto save do nothing, we only save when update button is clicked
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['rent_price'] ) ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $_POST['rent_price'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'rent_price', $_POST['rent_price'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'rent_price' );
}

//display rental field
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_rent_show', 20 );
function wc_rent_show() {
    global $product;
    // Do not show this on variable products
    if ( $product->product_type <> 'variable' ) {
        $rent = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rent_price', true );
    if ($rent > 0) {
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">';
        _e( 'Annual Rental: ', 'woocommerce' );
        echo '<span class="woocommerce-rent-price">' . woocommerce_price( $rent ) . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    }
}

// Optional: To show on archive pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_rent_show', 50 );
```